# getting out parameter from mysql stored procedure in java

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

I am having problem retrieving OUT parameter from mysql stored procedure in java.

```
CALL proc_after_topic_add('newtest',@result);
SELECT @result;
```

this query gives me desired out parameter but how would i retrieve it in java.I tried using CallableStatement but i get

```
java.sql.SQLException: Callable statments not supported.
```

error.Please guys help me.
I have tried following

```
String sql = "CALL proc_after_topic_add(?,?);";
            CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);
            cstmt.setString(1, topicname);
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            ResultSet rs = cstmt.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                if (rs.getInt(1) == 1) {
                    res = 0;
                } else {
                    res = -1;
                }
            }
```

I havent posted stored procedure code because there is nothing wrong with it.

```
PS:I a using mysql 5.5.21 and yes i should probably mention i am using mysql connector 3.0.15
```

**Okay this is solved.For anyone who encounters the same problem,just download latest version of mysql connector.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error in this line

```
 cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

change like this

```
 String sql = "CALL proc_after_topic_add(?,?);";
 cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

Comment: but i am still getting callable statement not supported error.Is it problem with mysql connector or mysql version.i am uing mysql 5.5.21

Comment: Canu debug the this code, and check whether error throwing form Sql Procedure, I dont think there will not be any issues related to version. but plese check that too veriosn, even if you can access the Callable statement, then issues from sql Procedure. Can u please post the Sql procedure

Answer (score 2):

```
Create a schema test and create a table employee in schema with 2 columns.  
id and employeename and insert some data.

Use this Stored Procedure.
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`get_count_name1` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE  `test`.`get_count_name1`(IN the_name VARCHAR(64),OUT     
the_count INT)

BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO the_count from employee where employeename=the_name;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Use this example.
    username and password are root and root for me. change as per your

    requirement. Here i am counting the occurence of employeename="deepak"**

```
import java.sql.*;
public class JDBCExample {
   // JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "root";
   static final String PASS = "root";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   CallableStatement stmt = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      String sql = "{call get_count_name1 (?, ?)}";
      stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);

      //Bind IN parameter first, then bind OUT parameter
      String name = "Deepak";
      stmt.setString(1, name); // This would set ID as 102
      // Because second parameter is OUT so register it
      stmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

      //Use execute method to run stored procedure.
      System.out.println("Executing stored procedure..." );
      stmt.execute();

     int count=stmt.getInt(2);
     System.out.println(count);
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }// nothing we can do
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}//end main
}//end JDBCExample
```