# Using mySql via proxy throws Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Callable statements not supported. after reconnect

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Hi guys i have this problem .I start my App then when its running I shut down mysql service and of course I starting to get `java.sql.SQLException: Callable statements not supported`. and it's ok after starting back the mySql service everything goes back to normal . The problem is when I use proxy between DataBase and my app and do exactly the same after starting mySql service I still get the exception.I know that proxy is working fine because I have checked telnet to DB and restarted the Application in both cases everything worked fine. So the question is what may cause this exception thanks.

P.S: 
It's maybe worth mentioning my App is Spring based Java application

Comment: what `exceptions` are you getting will you show us your error messages?

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Callable statements not supported it is in the question

Comment: What is your database version?

Comment: mysql version is 5.5.8

Comment: 5.5.8 not possible ...current version is 5.1.28.. i guess you are using old version download it again..

Comment: We use this connection for 3 years so I don't think it is driver issue

Comment: @urag - The problem that your JDBC driver is out of date.  Update it to the latest version ... and the problem should go away.

Answer (score 1):

As [stated on JavaGalaxy](http://www.javagalaxy.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=307#p552):

> MySQL has no support for Stored Procedures below MySQL version 5. So
>   if you are using MySQL Server below 5 try and upgrade to MySQL Server
>   version 5 or above.
>
> If you are receiving this error even when using MySQL 5 or above then
>   there is a possibility that the JDBC driver you are using is not
>   suitable for MySQL server version you are using. Try downloading MySQL
>   Connector/J Driver e.g. (mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar or above)

[click here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) to download MySQL.

Comment: This explanation is confirmed by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336557/getting-out-parameter-from-mysql-stored-procedure-in-java ... and by various postings in other places.

Comment: How can this answer be correct if I told you that everything works fine and only specific case when data base is connected via proxy and is disconnected for a moment the problem happens . Usually the procedures run fine .

Comment: If you copy the words of another site, you must properly attribute the source with blockquotes and a link, like I've done above. Please make sure you do this in the future.