# executing stored procedure in java application

Tags: java, mysql

I am executing a stored procedure in a java application, it has the following code:

```
CallableStatement cs = null;
cs= c.prepareCall("{CALL GetMaxId(?)}");
cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
cs.executeQuery();
this.valorDevuelto= cs.getInt(1);
System.out.println("It works ");
System.out.println(this.valorDevuelto);
cs.close();
System.out.println("Se cerro");
return true;
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("xDDDDD");
}
try{
st.close();
System.out.println("Se cerro");
}catch(Exception r){
}    
return false;
```

But when i execute it in the line of "

```
 cs= c.prepareCall("{CALL GetMaxId(?)}");"
```

I get the following exception :(

```
java.sql.SQLException: Callable statments not supported.
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.prepareCall(Connection.java:1284)
```

I don't know how to solve this, I have spent almost 2 hours and can't make it right.

Comment: What driver you are loading and version of jar you have in classpath?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Probably related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20867130/1743880)

Comment: I use jdk 1.7, I don't know how to check my driver version :(.

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver I have this in my code. I hope it can help D:

Comment: @Sebas see [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/installation-version.html) to determine your MySQL database version.

Comment: Notable the error trace `System.out.println("xDDDDD");` xd

Comment: this is the version: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.41